# Are result of queries using AWS Athena through AWS QuickSight stored in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I've checked AWS FAQ, and other resources however cannot find an answer to it. I can contact AWS for technical support however I do not have permission.

I've checked S3 that stores query results from Athena however it does not seem to have query results from queries using Athena via QuickSight.

Is there somewhere else Athena via QuickSight stores there query results?

thanks!

Comment: Hello - did you find an answer to your question?

Answer (score 3):

Athena always stores query results on S3. QuickSight probably just uses a different bucket. There should be queries from QuickSight in the query history (possibly in a work group that is not the primary), if you look at the query execution of one of these you should be able to figure out where the output is stored (e.g. `aws athena get-query-execution --region AWS_REGION --query-execution-id ID` and look for `OutputLocation` in the result).

Comment: Can the bucket configured for storage of Athena results be different from the bucket used to store results when QuickSight uses Athena?

Answer (score 0):

This answer comes a bit late but it says in the [Quicksight documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/troubleshoot-athena-workgroup.html):

"***The Athena workgroup must have an associated S3 output location.***"

So it seems Quicksight stores query results of a particular data source always in the bucket which is configured as output location for the Athena workgroup which is associated to this data source.